# Flutter SDK windows upgrade - Access denied, Cookies not found

Tags: windows, dart, flutter

I'm on windows and i tried to upgrade to the latest flutter sdk version but the error below kept appearing. FYI, i tried most fixes i found on GitHub. I downloaded the zipped file from their docs and unzipped in Documents as it has read/write permissions, turned off firewall, run `flutter doctor -v` in PowerShell, etc.

After running `flutter doctor -v`, this happened

```sh
λ flutter doctor -v
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/async_core.dart:28:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

export 'package:webdriver/src/async/cookies.dart';
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/web_driver.dart:20:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

import 'package:webdriver/src/async/cookies.dart';
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/sync_core.dart:35:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/sync/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

export 'package:webdriver/src/sync/cookies.dart';
^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/sync/web_driver.dart:25:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/sync/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

import 'package:webdriver/src/sync/cookies.dart';
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/handler/json_wire_handler.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/handler/json_wire/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

import 'package:webdriver/src/handler/json_wire/cookies.dart';
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/handler/w3c_handler.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/handler/w3c/cookies.dart': Access is denied.

import 'package:webdriver/src/handler/w3c/cookies.dart';
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/web_driver.dart:175:3: Error: Type 'Cookies' not found.
  Cookies get cookies => Cookies(_client, _handler);
  ^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/sync/web_driver.dart:183:3: Error: Type 'Cookies' not found.
  Cookies get cookies => Cookies(_client, _handler);
  ^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/web_driver.dart:175:26: Error: The method 'Cookies' isn't defined for the class 'WebDriver'.
 - 'WebDriver' is from 'package:webdriver/src/async/web_driver.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/async/web_driver.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Cookies'.
  Cookies get cookies => Cookies(_client, _handler);
                         ^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webdriver-2.1.2/lib/src/handler/json_wire_handler.dart:52:34: Error: Method not found: 'JsonWireCookiesHandler'.
  final CookiesHandler cookies = JsonWireCookiesHandler();
```

I keep coming back to this. Any fix?

Comment: Didn't see this exact issue before, but your `Documents` folder may require administrator rights. Try moving it to something like `C:/flutter` or `D:/dart` and change environment variables accordingly. I hope this helps.

Comment: I see you wrote it has permissions. I'm not entirely sure `Documents` does.

Comment: also, did you download a `stable` branch version?

Comment: You are right, Documents didn't have the administrator rights, so I moved the folder to D:\ but again the new SDK could not work, so i went to the previous one and applied some git commands i found on Flutter's GitHub issues. Thanks @AlexeySubbotin Detailed answer below

Answer (score 0):

It worked. FYI, i had not deleted the previous SDK, but placed it in D:\

Here is my fix:

- I turned off my firewall
- Moved to the old SDK folder (which resides in D:)
- Run the folder in CMD with administrator rights (i was using cmder)
- Replaced the flutter path in ENV with that of the previous SDK
- And then run:

```sh
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor -v
```